# Netbeans itacilized file name

Tags: netbeans

Today I opened netbeans after a month of not using it, and when I opened it all my program tabs with file names were italicized. This makes it a class like println, but the classes I am working on are my own files, and now I can't edit it.

How can I make them read and write files again?

Comment: Can't you "Add file(s) to project?"

Comment: By that would you mean adding those files in again? In that case no it has the same affect on the file, however creating a totally new file works.

Answer (score 0):

Italized file names mean that the files are read only. Are those files located on your computer or on a remote server? Did you have write access to project files? Do you have them as .java, .class, or .jar? To begin with right click on the tab, use select in projects and see what is selected.